# How can I get my RegEx to capture text on both sides of a colon?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, findall

I am trying to parse some input text from a file, which are originally grabbed from the Twitter API. The file is straight text and I am not actually grabbing the JSON in this case. This is a snippet of the input text:

```
.....HootSuite</a>", "text": "For independent news reports on the crisis in #Japan, 
see @DemocracyNow News Archive: http://ow.ly/4ht9Q
#nuclear #Fukushima #rdran #japon", "created_at": "Sat Mar 19.....
```

Basically I need to grab this:

```
"text": "For independent news reports "on" the crisis in #Japan, see @DemocracyNow 
News Archive: http://ow.ly/4ht9Q #nuclear #Fukushima #rdran #japon"
```

Here are the two I have tried to get working, but I am having some trouble with them:

```
    re.findall('"text":[^_]*',line)
    re.findall('"text":[^:}]+',line)
```

The first one will allow me to grab everything up to the "created" following the section I want. The second one kinda works as well but when the text includes a ":" it doesn't go until the end of the information

Anybody have some experience with RegEx that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're grabbing it from the Twitter API, can we assume you're grabbing the JSON?  Why not just pull the JSON value? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/

Comment: thats not a bad idea, good point. Here is a full line of data(well as much as I could paste)

{"favorited": false, "truncated": false, "source": "web", "text": "West Ham pushing back on the Spurs. A loss at home for Tottenham would be a serious setback to returning to Champions League play.", "created_at": "Sat Mar 19 14:19:19 +0000 2011", "retweeted": false,, "class": "politics", "entities": , "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "id_str": "49112718128594945", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "user": {"follow_request_sent": null, "profile_use_background_image": true, "id": 21619519,  }

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Twitter API, I imagine it's returning JSON back to you. JSON supports arbitrary nesting, and a regular expression will never be able to parse it correctly in every scenario. You would be better served using a JSON parser. Since YAML is a superset of JSON, you could use a YAML parser too. I would take a look at [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org). (It's what I know. They're are probably just JSON parsers out there too)

Then parsing is would be as easy as:

```
import yaml
results = yaml.load(twitter_response)
print results["text"]  # This would contain the string you're interested in.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) to parse the JSON.

Follow this tutorial: http://blogs.openshine.com/pvieytes/2011/05/18/parsing-twitter-user-timeline-with-python/

Comment: unfortunately I am not using the twitter API directly. The information is grabbed from a given input file which is simply text format so simplejason would not help me in this particular situation

Comment: It still will help you. Just use the text file as the input. simplejson is a JSON parser. The input text file is still JSON data whether it is directly grabbed from Twitter or not.

Answer (score 0):

Json is a simple enough format that you don't always need a parser if you're trying to do something trivial.  Consider the example line:

```
>>> line = """{ "text" : "blah blah foo", "other" : "blah blah bar" }"""
```

Here are two ways to do what you want.

With regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('"text"\ *:\ *"([^"]*)',line)
>>> m.group()
'"text" : "blah blah bar'
>>> m.group(1)
'blah blah bar'
```

With eval (json is a very pythonic format):

```
>>> d = eval(line)
>>> d['text']
'blah blah bar'
```